# Create individual worksheets from a master worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Staff    ClientFname     ClientLname    Phone#    DateNextCall    DateLastCalled

I have a Master_Case_List worksheet that contains all clients for all staff with above column headings. I want to go through each row in the Master_Case_List and produce separate worksheets (in that same workbook) for each staff (same column headings) with only their clients in it . . . but with 2 options (asking for input from the user):

Option 1: Only clients whose DateNextCall <= today (Staff’s Daily Call List)
  Option 2: All clients for that staff member (Staff’s Entire Client List)

What I've tried: I've tried a pivot table (which I've used mostly for calculations before), but can't seem to get it to produce what I need here.  Filters would work, but I want to "automate" it for admin staff to use daily.

I'm new to vba and only used it on an active worksheet; not familiar with going back/forth between worksheets. So when I tried the following to set the Master worksheet, I get "Subscript out of range":

Dim ThisWorkbook As Workbook
Dim MasterCaseList As Worksheet
Set ThisWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set MasterCaseList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master_Case_List") 'get error "Subscript out of range"

Comment: Since SO isn't meant to be a code-writing service, can you [edit] your question with what you've tried and why it's not working? Thanks!

Comment: Duplicating data like this is not good practice. Why not just create a report on the existing data with a Pivot table or filters?

Comment: Dim ThisWorkbook As Workbook
Dim MasterCaseList As Worksheet
Set ThisWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set MasterCaseList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master_Case_List")   I keep getting subscript out of range"

Comment: Wow.  I cannot respond productively or even politely. So I will delete my answer and leave you alone. I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: Profoundly Oblivious, sorry for any frustration I've caused. I'm new to such forums and to vba.  I'm just trying to figure out how to get something done that I was trying to do for DAYS by myself, using some of the same constructs.  My apologies.